# Is there a way to return the number of bad records loaded to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way using the Python API to get the number of bad records from a job when I load to a BigQuery dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Below is stats available for load job:

```
statistics.load nested          object  [Output-only] Statistics for a load job.
statistics.load.inputFileBytes  long    [Output-only] Number of bytes of source data in a load job.
statistics.load.inputFiles      long    [Output-only] Number of source files in a load job.
statistics.load.outputBytes     long    [Output-only] Size of the loaded data in bytes. Note that while a load job is in the running state, this value may change.
statistics.load.outputRows      long    [Output-only] Number of rows imported in a load job. Note that while an import job is in the running state, this value may change.
```

If you know expected rows number you can figure out bad ones using outputRows

Meantime -  you can control number of bad records allowed in your load job:

```
configuration.load.allowJaggedRows
configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues
configuration.load.maxBadRecords
```

All this can be found in
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load

and
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.load